# Trying to calculate the average on a count of records in my query results

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to create a query in Application Insights that can show me the absolute and average number of messages in conversations over a particular time period. I'm using the LUIS trace example to get the context+LUIS information, which is where I'm pulling the conversationID from. I can get a table showing the number of messages per conversation, but I would also like to have a average number of messages for the data set. Either static average or rolling average (by pulling in timestamp) would be fine. I can get this value by doing a second summarize statement, but then I lose the granularity from the first. Here is my query.

```
requests
| where url endswith "messages"
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| project timestamp, url, id
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)http://"botName".azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| where message == "LUIS"
| extend convID = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_botContext_conversation_id)
| order by timestamp desc nulls last
| project timestamp, botName, convID
| summarize messages=count() by conversation=convID
```

This gives me a table of conversation IDs with the message count for each conversation. I would also like to see the average number of messages per conversation. For example, if I have 4 conversations with 100 messages total, I want to see that the average is 25. I can get this result by doing a second summarize statement `| summarize messages=sum(messages), avgMessages=avg(messages)`, but then of course I can no longer see the individual conversations. Is there any way to see both in the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this without losing granularity from the first list (i.e. I couldn't figure out how to calculate average per period e.g. day), but the following query does at least get me the average across whatever timestamp filter I set, which ultimately gets me at the data I was looking for.

```sql
requests
| where url endswith "messages"
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| project timestamp, url, id
| parse kind = regex url with *"(?i)http://"botName".azurewebsites.net/api/messages"
| join kind= inner (
traces | extend id = operation_ParentId
) on id
| where message == "LUIS"
| extend convID = tostring(customDimensions.LUIS_botContext_conversation_id)
| order by timestamp desc nulls last
| project timestamp, botName, convID
| summarize messages=count() by conversation=convID
| summarize conversations=count(), messageAverage=avg(messages)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write 2 queries, one for "gives me a table of conversation IDs with the message count for each conversation", and another for " the average number of messages per conversation". And consider use [Let statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/letstatement#using-materialize-function) for your query.

The tricky here is that, in both of the 2 queries, after the `summarize` statement, add this line of code at the end, like  `| extend myidentifier="aaa"` .

Then you can join the 2 queries by using `myidentifier`.

Comment: OK I added the identifier but I'm not real familiar with Kusto queries. How do I do I join? In all the examples I see join is using the standard data buckets like "requests" and "traces". How do I join those two queries together?

Comment: @billoverton, you can take a look at this [let statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/letstatement#using-materialize-function), you can define 2 let statements, one for your 1st query, and the other for your 2nd query, then use join.

Comment: I need to try some more. As of yet I haven't quite figured out how to get all of this working together. You've pointed me in a good direction to explore some other methods but I haven't figured out how to do the join yet.

Comment: @billoverton, I don't have the same source data as yours, but I will provide a sample with similar data later.